# Problems with connecting to VM with cucumber remote test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, remote-server, selenium-webdriver

I have a cucumber test suite I want to run in Internet Explorer environment the problem is that I am on a linux machine. So I thried to follow this, somewhat outdated, [guide](http://www.johng.co.uk/2010/10/13/run_capybara_and_cucumber_features_in_internet_explorer_on_remote_windows/).

I'm using a local VM to try and run the tests on and there I have started the standalone selenium server which tells me that:

`RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.1:4444/wb/hub`

Now this seems a bit odd that I have localhost here as connect to but no matter it's on the same physical machine so should pose no problems or?

Well next in my `env.rb` I have defined the following:

```
Capybara.app_host = "http://hostname:4444"
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app,
    :browser => :remote,
    :url => "http://MYNETWORKIP:4444/wd/hub",
    :desired_capabilities => :internet_explorer)
end
```

as the guide suggests. But when I run the test I get the following error:

```
bad URI(is not URI?): 127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub (URI::InvalidURIError)
```

I suspect it has something to do with me being behind a proxy since I needed to do some special settings for Firefox(iceweasel) to run.
Those settings were:

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  profile                                       =   Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
  profile["network.proxy.type"]                 =   2
  profile["network.proxy.autoconfig_url"]       =   "http config adress here"
  profile["network.proxy.no_proxies_on"]        =   "localhost, 127.0.0.1, #{%x[hostname].gsub("\n", "")}"
  profile["network.proxy.http"]                 =   "proxy http address here"
  profile["network.proxy.http_port"]            =   3128
  profile["network.proxy.ssl"]                  =   "ssl proxy http address here"
  profile["network.proxy.ssl_port"]             =   3128
  profile["network.proxy.share_proxy_settings"] =   true
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :profile => profile)
end
```

Spent alot of time trying to get this to work now so I need some help
Thx in advance

EDIT:

Realized that some versions might be of help.
From gemfile:

```
 cucumber (1.1.9)
 rails (2.3.11)
 selenium-webdriver (2.20.0)
```

EDIT 2:

Further tries with changing the url to my network ip address gives me another error:

```
both URI are relative (URI::BadURIError)
```

EDIT 3:

Now with the help of Jon M I get a bit further but encountering:

```
 unexpected response, code=404, content-type="text/html"
```

EDIT 4:

Latest update:

Changed the connection settings in my `env.rb`

This gives me a connection to my virtualbox and starts up my IE browser YAY!
BUT! It cannot connect to the application.

Comment: Just added a bit more to my answer but can you clarify where the selenium server is running?  You say it's on a local VM, but then elsewhere say it's 'on the same machine'.  If it is actually a VM then you'll have to establish connectivity to the VM guest from the host, which may involve setting up a host-only network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect the 'bad URI' message is due to the missing protocol - try prefixing '127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub' with 'http://'

Edit (in response to your update):

Just spotted the address...  127.0.0.1 refers to `localhost`, but if the Selenium server is running on a different machine, surely you should be using the IP address of that machine?

e.g. http://some.other.ip:4444/wd/hub

Comment: That seems to be part of the problem yes. Still not working correctly though. Will get back when I have tried some more

Comment: If I use my network Ip address I get a connection timeout I feel that a 404 is a bit closer atleast. Also It is on the same physical machine but I am using a VirtualBox where I'm running windows 7 and the selenium-standalone-server

Comment: Are you running cucumber on the Windows VirtualBox guest?  Or is that running on the linux/mac host?

Comment: I don't understand your questions completely but I run my tests from my normal linux os, and I want it to connect to my selenium server on my windows Vitrual box

Comment: I got it working now. You were right even though it was all on the same physical machine I still needed to use my network ip. Also I had forgot that I had hardcoded my server port and did not use the same port in my app_host