# How to test remote server deployment of Rails app with Cucumber and Capybara

Tags: testing, ruby-on-rails-3.2, cucumber, capybara, remote-server

I am developing a Rails 3.x app under Windows 7 and am using Cucumber and Capybara for testing.

I have set up an Ubuntu VM and deployed my app to that.

I want to use Cucumber / Capybara to test my app on the VM after each deployment - after all, this is a different OS and I want to leverage the power of my test suite to test different browsers (Firefox, Chrome and IE) against the deployed site.

In theory, it seems as though I have 3 main options:

1) Run Cucumber locally, with a local browser and hit the remote server (VM guest)
2) Run Cucumber locally with a remote browser hitting the remote server
3) Connect to the VM guest and run Cucumber locally under the VM

It seems to me that option 1) best simulates the real world, ie NOT running the browser on the remote server.

However, I am not sure if this is possible, or how to configure things to achieve it. In particular I am not clear whether or not I need Selenium Server in this case, and if I do, whether I should be deploying it locally (on the Windows dev machine) or remotely (in the guest VM where the app is deployed).

I have done a fair bit of Google searching about this issue and have looked at such posts as:

[Problems with connecting to VM with cucumber remote test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880342/problems-with-connecting-to-vm-with-cucumber-remote-test)

https://github.com/leonid-shevtsov/headless

and while these give some clues such as the use of (which are exactly as described in the official Capybara docs at http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara)

```
  Capybara.app_host = "http://hostname:4444"
  Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
  Capybara.run_server = false
```

the examples given seem to be referring to the browser running remotely (eg my Options 2 or 3) and I am still not sure what is the best approach to take.